# Showing login XRDP screen once, when trying login user its disappearing again its showing RDP setup screen

Tags: xrdp

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and installed XRDP and XFCE4 after this, when I am executing `sudo service xrdp restart` it shows a message:

```
It looks like xrdp is allready running, 
if not delete the xrdp.pid file and try again
```

Getting XRDP Sesman-Xvnc login screen, trying login it automatically again reverts to the RDP setup screen.
Kinldy help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If `pgrep xrdp` shows no `xrdp` actually running, `locate xrdp.pid` will find the file (or read the documentation) that you should delete.

`progname.pid` files are traditionally used as lock files. That is, a program that wants to prevent 2 copies running at the same time will write it's `PID` into a `progname.pid` file, and plan to remove it when exiting. If a normal exit is precluded (User types `^C`, system crashes, etc) the `.pid` file can be left hanging around.

Once you `locate xrdp.pid`, it's content should be the PID of the program that created it. `ps -fp` followed by the PID will show you the current status. E.g. `ps -fp $(cat xrdp.pid)`. If `ps` shows nothing, the process that created the file no longer exists, and `xrdp.pid` can be deleted without worry.